# UML Modeling sequence diagram calling/using database

Tags: uml

In a sequence diagram if my method `get_user_by_id( id )` calls the database  or uses a framework that have a `dbSet` containing collections of `users` for example. how do i call it in a diagram i can't find find documentation about this.
by documentation i mean maybe a lot of documents or a book that have it's content or part of it available for free. i know that using something like `: Set(User)` means it's a collection of that class that and the database is, well, data? magic?

 
Note : i am talking about `UML 2` in case there is a difference with `UML 1.x` 
**the source code using `dbSet`**

```
public partial class DBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DBEntities()
            : base("name=DBEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ClassA> AdmExportDefinition { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ClassB> AdmImportModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ClassC> AdmImportModFields { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Because you mention "dbSet", I guess you have source code in mind and you want to know how to reflect that source code in a diagram. Could you provide the line(s) of code you want to model? It is not entirely clear what you mean by "call the database". Do you mean executing a SQL statement?

Comment: What do you mean by "how do i call it in a diagram"? I usually call routines or persons, but never a diagram. It won't listen.